# Disable general filter from inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I have 3 filters which affect both an array and a nested array, both displayed with ng-repeat.

It's displayed like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="pa in products | filter:one | filter:two | filter:three">
    <div ng-repeat="vari in pa.variacions | filter:two | filter:three">
    </div>    
</div>
```

The filters work great.
The problem comes when I try to add a button inside the first array to disable filters. So far **it only disables filters in the particular item** of the ng-repeat, while **the desire effect is that it disables the filters for all the items**.

This is how it looks like:

```
<div ng-repeat="pa in products | filter:one | filter:two | filter:three">
    <div ng-repeat="vari in pa.variacions | filter:two | filter:three">
    </div>   

    <a ng-click="one = {}; two = {}; three = {}">Show all</a>
</div>
```

How could I manage to make this button kill the filters for all items in the ng-repeat and not only for the one?

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible, works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

`ng-repeat` creates child scopes. So since you are reassigning scope properties at child scope level it isn't modifying the originals.

Use a function so the properties get re-assigned at top level in controller. The subsequent digest cycle will update the child scopes

```
<a ng-click="reset()">Show all</a>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.reset = function(){
  ['one','two','three'].forEach(function(prop){
      $scope[prop] = {};
  })
}
```

If you were using `controllerAs` this issue wouldn't exist ... or if you were using one object for all the filters and you updated that object's properties in the view

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Might it be cause I define the filter in the HTML instead of in the controller? `<a ng-click="one = {'pages': true}; ">Pagès</a>`

Comment: Yes.... if that is defined in child scope . Same idea, move it to a function that will get inherited all the way down the scope

Comment: Is not, the links to activate the filters are outside the ng-repeat! : )

Comment: try changing only properties instead of overwriting whole object...like `ng-click="one.pages = true "`. Still best to use functions for such scope changes

Comment: A plunker demo that reproduces problem would also help